# VBA script to copy cell values in column to cell address given in other column

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to do the following:

I have one column with values and one column with cell addresses. I want to copy the values in column A to the cell addresses in column B. The VBA script should run till there is an empty cell.

```
   A       B       C     D     E

 1 *       C1
 2 $       E3
 3 à       C2
```

after I run the macro I should have:

```
   A       B       C     D     E

 1 *       C1      *
 2 $       E3      à
 3 à       C2                  $
```

Comment: What is some of the code you've tried or started with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub copyValues()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cel As Range, ur As Range

    Set ws = Sheet1

    Set ur = ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each cel In ur
        If Len(cel.Offset(0, 1)) > 0 Then ws.Range(cel.Offset(0, 1).Value2) = cel
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Sub CopyPasteCellValues()

    Dim lastrow As Long, x As Long
    Dim RangeValues As Range, cell As Range
    Dim address As String

    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'RangeValues is a collection of all cell values that are supposed to be copied and pasted
    Set RangeValues = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, 1))

    x = 1

    For Each cell In RangeValues
        address = Cells(x, 2).Value
        Range(address) = Cells(x, 1)
        x = x + 1
    Next cell

End Sub
```